# Reference initialization forms

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, c++14

So I was testing some of the reference initialization forms, described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization). I wonder when the:

```
T & ref = { arg1, arg2, ... };
```

and

```
T && ref = { arg1, arg2, ... };
```

forms will be ever used and for what exactly. I suppose it's for initializing temporary arrays and constructors with 'initializer_list', like this:

```
int main()
{


    struct _ab
    {
        _ab() {cout << "_ab()" << endl;}

        _ab(initializer_list<int> iArr) : a(*iArr.begin()), b(*iArr.end()) {cout << "_ab()" << endl;}

        ~_ab() {cout << "~_ab()" << endl;}
        int a, b;
    };
    const _ab & i = {1, 2};

    cout << i.a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this context I tried to initialize the const reference with a temporary '_ab' object using the default constructor like this:

```
int main()
    {


        struct _ab
        {
            _ab() {cout << "_ab()" << endl;}

            _ab(initializer_list<int> iArr) : a(*iArr.begin()), b(*iArr.end()) {cout << "_ab()" << endl;}

            ~_ab() {cout << "~_ab()" << endl;}
            int a, b;
        };
        const _ab & i(); // error 1

        cout << i.a << endl; // error 2

        return 0;
    }
```

But this example didn't compile with 2 errors:

> error 1: 'const main()::_ab& i()', declared using local type 'const
>   main()::_ab', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]|
>
> error 2: request for member 'a' in 'i', which is of non-class type
>   'const main()::_ab&()'|

Can you enlighten me about what exactly the above 2 construct means & are used for.

EDIT: I understand the problem with the second example. It was declaring a function instead of variable. But still can somebody explain me why references have the possibility to be initialized with initialization list and for what is it used?

Comment: Tangentially, `_ab` is a strange name for a type ... what's wrong with `ab`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const _ab & i();
```

The standard explains this in a note in [dcl.init]/8:

> [ *Note:* Since `()` is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> ```
> X a();
> ```
>
> is not the declaration of an object of class `X`, but the declaration
>   of a function taking no argument and returning an `X`.

This applies regardless of the type and is referred to as the most vexing parse. Of course `i.a` is thus ill-formed.

---

> But still can somebody explain me why references have the possibility
>   to be initialized with initialization list and for what is it used?

[dcl.init]/3:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - [..]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>     reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from
>     that element; if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to
>     convert the element to T, the program is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is copy-list-initialized or
>     direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for
>     the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary.
>   [ *Note:* As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the
>     reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. *— end note* ]

The last note refers to the fact that

```
int& i = {1};
```

Is ill-formed since we would have to bind `1` to a non-const lvalue reference, which isn't possible. Neither would

```
std::string& s = {20, '5'};
```

be valid since we have to initialize a non-const lvalue reference with a temporary.
The standard then gives examples:

```
struct S {
    S(std::initializer_list<double>); // #1
    S(const std::string&);            // #2
    // ...
};

const S& r1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 };    // OK: invoke #1
const S& r2 { "Spinach" };      // OK: invoke #2
S& r3 = { 1, 2, 3 };            // error: initializer is not an lvalue
const int& i1 = { 1 };          // OK
const int& i2 = { 1.1 };        // error: narrowing
const int (&iar)[2] = { 1, 2 }; // OK: iar is bound to temporary array
```

This can also be particularly useful for function calls.

```
void f(std::vector<int> const&);

f( {first, last} );
```

Answer (score 3):

`const _ab & i();`

Above code declares <strike>(and calls)</strike> a *function* that returns a const reference to _ab struct - that's the first error. The second error is that you try to access a member variable of a function (`i`), which is not possible.

To use default constructor you could use the new `{...}` C++11 syntax, it should work in your example

```
const _ab & i {}; // probably will work fine
```

however omiting the braces will lead to an error - this one will not work:

```
const _ab & i;  // error
```

This should also work fine:

```
const _ab & i = {};
```

EDIT:

You can initialize reference with an "anonymous" object (like in all your examples) only if that is a `const` reference. It's allowed in the language, I'm not sure there's any deeper reason for that and why it shouldn't be allowed. So you don't actually initialize reference with initializer list (or whatever) - these are used to initialize an anonymous object, and this anonymous object is used as a "target" for the const reference. If you'd declare the constructor to be `explicit`, you'd need to specify the type, so maybe in that case it wouldn't be so confusing as for what the initializer is actually used:

```
const _ab & i = _ab{/*...*/};
```

This is equivalent to:

```
const _ab anonymousObject = _ab{/*...*/};
const _ab & i = anonymousObject;
```

Comment: So actually those initialization list forms of initializing a reference are used to create a temporary object with them.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is similar to the case that allows binding an rvalue to a const-reference e.g.

```
std::string str() { return "blah"; }

const std::string& s = str();
```

The prvalue returned by the function is bound to the reference and its lifetime is extended until the reference's lifetime ends.

Another way to exercise that same rule is just by creating a temporary object directly:

```
const std::string& s = std::string();
```

This creates a temporary which is bound to the reference (extending its lifetime to the reference's lifetime).

The case of `const _ab& i = {1, 2}` is very similar, but relies on an implicit temporary of type `_ab` being constructed from the braced-init-list i.e. it's similar to this:

```
const _ab& i = _ab{1, 2};
```

(The difference is that the first form won't work if the initializer_list constructor for `_ab` is `explicit` whereas the second one will work even for explicit constructors ... but marking initializer-list constructors `explicit` is a bad idea and should be avoided, because it makes it difficult and confusing to initialize objects).

This syntax isn't necessarily useful exactly as written above, because you'd usually just write `const _ab{1, 2};` instead of using a reference. But when you are calling a function that takes a const-reference it's useful to be able to initialize the argument with a braced-init-list, e.g. a function taking `std::pair<int, const char*>` can be called as `func({1, "two"})`, which is more convenient than the C++03 equivalent: `func(std::make_pair(1, "two"))`. In order for that to work, it has to be possible for list-initialization of references to cause the implicit creation of a temporary, which leads to the `const _ab& = {1, 2}` form you're asking about.